# Python: Printing a new line after a recursive function

Tags: python, recursion

I'm writing a tree traversal method. The output needs to be on one line. When the method is complete, though, I'd like to insert a line break. Is there any way to do this within the function, or will it have to be called from outside?

Right now I have:

```
def postorder_transversal(self):
    if self.node == None:
        return 0
    for child in self.children:
        child.postorder_transversal()
    print self.node,
```

Any thoughts on how to alter it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it inside the function like so:

```
def postorder_transversal(self, add_newline=True):
    if self.node == None:
        return 0
    for child in self.children:
        child.postorder_transversal(add_newline=False)
    print self.node,
    if add_newline:
        print
```

though it may be cleaner to just do it outside.

Comment: Thanks! This is really elegant and compact

Comment: @Adam_G: By the way, you can "do it outside" just by making the recursive function a local function or separate method, and having `postorder_traversal(self)` just call that other function, then `print`. And I think, as Dougal says, that may be cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

You could pass the depth as a parameter:

```
def postorder_transversal(self, depth=0):
    if self.node == None:
        return 0

    for child in self.children:
        child.postorder_transversal(depth=depth + 1)

    print self.node,

    if depth == 0:
        print
```

And with the `print` function:

```
from __future__ import print_function

def postorder_transversal(self, depth=0):
    if self.node == None:
        return 0

    for child in self.children:
        child.postorder_transversal(depth=depth + 1)

    print(self.node, end='\n' * (depth == 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

After this function backs out of recursion, it will print a bunch of nodes. Right after that, add a newline to stdout. So yes, outside.